# Select MySQL If (ID) In Array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I trying to build a notification system (CodeIgniter) and not store it in my database by this unique ID. Now I got some problem to using `SELECT query.

[image: IMG]

Also this is array stored in "value" row:

```
[{"id":0,"user_id":"1","comment":"That's a Nice Video.","posttime":1403523177,"status":1},{"id":1,"user_id":"4","comment":"Nice to see this..!!","posttime":1403590409,"status":1}]
```

And this is my (not work) query:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('post_meta',array('status'=>1),in_array('user_id', $id));
```

Ideas?

Note: Notification will be sparated by "user_id".

Comment: what does it show when you run that? what error mesage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `in_array('user_id', $id)` on that function because it returns boolean.

On the active record page: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html you can take a look at parameter it takes for `get_where()` function

`$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);`

Notice how the third parameter takes **$limit** which talks about the number of data you'll receive. (Leaving this blank will return you all data).

---

**Some code examples:**

If you just want to get the data with `status = 1`, use the following:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('post_meta',array('status'=>1));
```

If you want to get the data with `status = 1` and `user_id = $id`, use the following:

```
$this->db->like('value', '"user_id":"'.$id.'"'); 
$query = $this->db->get_where('post_meta',array('status'=>1));
```

The solution above is not the best, but it should work.
The `$this->db->like()` function will create rules to get data in `value` row which has `"user_id":"$id"` where **$id** is the value that you define.

---

**What if I want to get all notifications and group them based on their ID?**

I usually get all the data and then use PHP to group them into its own array. I think it's cheaper than relying on database to do that (Correct me if i'm wrong).

So use the first code:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('post_meta',array('status'=>1));
```

Then iterate them using `foreach()` or whatever you find convenient.

```
$data = array();
foreach($query as $k=>$v) {
    // Run a function to get User ID
    $user_id = your_function_here($v->value);

    if(!isset($data[$user_id]))
        $data[$user_id] = array();

    // This is just some example to group them together, you can optimize it to your own liking
    array_push($data[$user_id],$v);
}
```

`your_function_here()` is your function to get the user_id from `value` row on your database.

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. But problems came again after I adding some features. The query may using JOIN TABLE to another. Will make this query first.

*EDIT: Salam kenal :D